# How to specify which @Recover method to use for which @Retryable method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry, recover

So, I've a spring boot app, where in my service class, there are multiple methods that I'm retrying using `@Retryable` on them. I've also created their respective recovery methods using `@Recover` annotation for them.

Now, a lot of these service methods have the same attributes in method signature; due to which their recover methods end up having the same signature as well.

The problem this is leading to is that the recovery method selection on retry exhaustion is NOT as expected. I'm seeing that the recover method declared under method1 is getting called when method3 fails after all retries.

Is there a way to control the recovery method selection? I've seen the use of  RetryTemplate where the RetryCallback and RecoveryCallback are explicitly provided, is that the only way?

Thanks!

Here's what the code looks like:

```
@Retryable
public boolean method1(String arg1) {
// do something
}

@Recover
public boolean method1Recovery(Exception e, String arg1) {
//do something
}

.
.
.

@Retryable
public boolean method3(String arg1) {
// do something
}

@Recover
public boolean method3Recovery(Exception e, String arg1) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: Another way that would probably work is to define and use different exception types, e.g. `Method1Exception` … `Method3Exception`.

Comment: That sounds fair, but it will create multiple exception classes just to work around this. I wish I didn't have to do that. But thanks for the suggestion, seems like the easiest work around.

Comment: @slauth if you would post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Please do so. Thanks!

Comment: Another way suggested by a colleague was to throw different exceptions (that are subclasses of a base-exception) from methods and use the same recovery to check `instanceOf` and determine how to handle each one. But again, this depends on having individual exceptions for each of the methods like @slauth suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way that would probably work is to define and use different exception types, e.g. `Method1Exception` … `Method3Exception`.